# Connecting to server which is conncet to VPN

Tags: server, internet, vpn, traffic

I have a server and nordvpn account. What I want is that I want to conncet my server with ssh and then in my server I want to conncet my vpn. I want to use my server with vpn.

I install openvpn to my server and when conncet my nordvpn my connection with my server is down of course vpn change my ip. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try following:

Find out the ip adress of the ssh-client `curl ifconfig.co`

Than log in to your server and find out it's gateway ip: `ip route`

```
ip route
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlan0  proto static  metric 600 
192.168.3.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.1 linkdown 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.66  metric 600
```

In my case my gateway has the ip 192.168.178.1

Now set up a route (in your server) like this: `ip route add client-ssh-ip via gateway-ip` in my case: `ip route add 80.128.240.55 via 192.168.178.1`

Now you can try to activate your vpn and check if you are still able to log in via ssh. As soon as you reboot your server the route rule will be lost. As soon as your ISP changes your IP the route rule will become useless either. Perhaps as an alternative you can bind your ssh port to the gateway somehow with iptables but i never did this.

Comment: It didn't work, when I conncet to my vpn client my ssh connection down. How about binding my ssh port to gateway? I google it but it came to me so networking thing complex. Can you give me more details about it?

Comment: i don't know why it did not work for you because i do it that way. i add a route and start the vpn via terminal. perhaps you did not select the correct ip's?

Comment: Yes you are right, I put the ips wrong places. Now, I can maintain my ssh conncetion and I can able to connect VPN over openvpn. However there is another issue, I could not conncet the internet in my DigitalOcean server. Probably there is a firewall to block VPN but I am not sure about it. My VPN provider has an option obfuscate VPN to bypass these firewalls. However when I install my VPN client and run it terminal, my ssh conncetion is down. I think when connect the vpn over my vpn client, it changes the routing settings.

Comment: to me it is not clear what u mean: SSH is working while your VPN connection is established?

Comment: yeah I connected to vpn and maintain my ssh connection and then I want to check my ip adress in my server and I saw my internet wont work

Comment: to me this looks like a new question ... your openvpn-client confirms "Initialization Sequence Completed"? how does your client.conf look? are u sure it is not a DNS problem? if u can make sure that this problem persists regardless of the new created route i suggest you to create a new question

Comment: Hımm let me check the DNS. Yes I can see  "Initialization Sequence Completed" on the terminal

Comment: in case it's a dns problem you can try to append the following three lines to your client conf and retry: `script-security 2`
 `up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`
 `down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`
`

Comment: yesss it is working! thank you so much:) As you mention my problem is my dns. I changed my dns whit these comments:

Comment: sudo apt install resolvconf

Edit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head and add the following:

# Make edits to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head.
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8

sudo service resolvconf restart